# i need to convert array value to json in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i have array value. need to convert this array value into json format. example is given bleow

Sample Array

```
[Management Portal!@!@Production Issue Handling!@!@/IONSWeb/refDataManagement/searchDynamicScripts.do, Management Portal!@!@ Event Browser!@!@/IONSWeb/orderManagement/eventBrowser.do, Management Portal!@!@ Order Workflow!@!@/IONSWeb/orderManagement/SearchOrdersWorkflow.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Admin Message!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/getMessageForBroadcast.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Audit!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/auditManagement.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Locks!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/lockSearch.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Queue!@!@/IONSWeb/GroupManagement/begin.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Role!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/goToRolePage.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Routing Rule!@!@/IONSWeb/ruleManagement/showRules.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Task Code!@!@/IONSWeb/ManageTaskCode/begin.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Trigger OutEvent!@!@/IONSWeb/triggerOutEvent.jsp, ADMINISTRATION!@!@User!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/begin.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Refresh Application Cache!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/refreshApplnCache.do]
```

sample Json

```
{
  "name": "Administration",      
  "sub": [
       {
          "name": "Add Order",
          "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/auditManagement.do"
        },
        {
          "name": "Infrastructure sonet Add Order ",
          "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/auditManagement.do"
        },
        {
          "name": "fGNS Add Order",
          "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/auditManagement.do"
        }           
]
}
```

Please anyone help on this

Comment: That is not an array in JavaScript.

Comment: So do you have this string, and you want a JSON from this?

Comment: SO is not **get code for free** site. Please share what you have achieved so far.

Comment: @nils,  yes. i changed this to array using  var myArr = myStr.split("!@!@");

Comment: i dont have idea to create this array to json

Comment: @Ganeshsah show us the direct array, not this string which is not an array.

Comment: Also, post what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ug85d7o7/6/

```
var jsonData = [], 
    item, name,
    subItem, subUrl,
    i, j,
    a = [
        "Management Portal!@!@Production Issue Handling!@!@/IONSWeb/refDataManagement/searchDynamicScripts.do", 
        "Management Portal!@!@ Event Browser!@!@/IONSWeb/orderManagement/eventBrowser.do",
        "Management Portal!@!@ Order Workflow!@!@/IONSWeb/orderManagement/SearchOrdersWorkflow.do", 
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Admin Message!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/getMessageForBroadcast.do", 
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Audit!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/auditManagement.do",
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Locks!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/lockSearch.do",
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Queue!@!@/IONSWeb/GroupManagement/begin.do", 
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Role!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/goToRolePage.do", 
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Routing Rule!@!@/IONSWeb/ruleManagement/showRules.do", 
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Task Code!@!@/IONSWeb/ManageTaskCode/begin.do", 
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Trigger OutEvent!@!@/IONSWeb/triggerOutEvent.jsp",
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@User!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/begin.do",
        "ADMINISTRATION!@!@Refresh Application Cache!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/refreshApplnCache.do"
    ];

for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
    item = a[i].split("!@!@");
    name = item[0];
    subName = item[1];
    subUrl = item[2];

    subItem = null;
    for (j=0; j<jsonData.length; j++)
    {
        if (jsonData[j].Name == name)
        {
            subItem = jsonData[j].sub;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!subItem)
    {
        jsonData.push({"Name" : name, "sub" : [] });
        subItem = jsonData[jsonData.length-1].sub;        
    }

    subItem.push({"Name" : subName, "url" : subUrl });
}

alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Management Portal",
    "sub": [
      {
        "Name": "Production Issue Handling",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/refDataManagement/searchDynamicScripts.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": " Event Browser",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/orderManagement/eventBrowser.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": " Order Workflow",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/orderManagement/SearchOrdersWorkflow.do"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "ADMINISTRATION",
    "sub": [
      {
        "Name": "Admin Message",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/getMessageForBroadcast.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Audit",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/auditManagement.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Locks",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/lockSearch.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Queue",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/GroupManagement/begin.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Role",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/goToRolePage.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Routing Rule",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/ruleManagement/showRules.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Task Code",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/ManageTaskCode/begin.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Trigger OutEvent",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/triggerOutEvent.jsp"
      },
      {
        "Name": "User",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/begin.do"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Refresh Application Cache",
        "url": "/IONSWeb/userManagement/refreshApplnCache.do"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping on this, it is working fine. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this. Split the string, get out the first element, that will be the name, and iterate through all the elements. Every even value will be the name, and every odd an url.

When it is odd, then add it to the sub array. Thats it.

```
    var string = 'Management Portal!@!@Production Issue Handling!@!@/IONSWeb/refDataManagement/searchDynamicScripts.do, Management Portal!@!@ Event Browser!@!@/IONSWeb/orderManagement/eventBrowser.do, Management Portal!@!@ Order Workflow!@!@/IONSWeb/orderManagement/SearchOrdersWorkflow.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Admin Message!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/getMessageForBroadcast.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Audit!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/auditManagement.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Locks!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/lockSearch.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Queue!@!@/IONSWeb/GroupManagement/begin.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Role!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/goToRolePage.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Routing Rule!@!@/IONSWeb/ruleManagement/showRules.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Task Code!@!@/IONSWeb/ManageTaskCode/begin.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Trigger OutEvent!@!@/IONSWeb/triggerOutEvent.jsp, ADMINISTRATION!@!@User!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/begin.do, ADMINISTRATION!@!@Refresh Application Cache!@!@/IONSWeb/userManagement/refreshApplnCache.do';
    var pieces = string.split('!@!@');
    var first = pieces[0];
    //Get out the first one, that will be the key
    pieces.shift();
    //Create the object
    var object = {
        'name': first,
        'sub': []
    };

    //Iterate through elements
    var i = 0;
    var sub = [];
    $.each(pieces, function (idx, piece) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sub['name'] = piece;
        } else {
            sub['url'] = piece;
            object.sub.push(sub);
        }
        i++;
    });
    console.log(object);
```